# How to fix gdb : Giving weird error message

Tags: json, linux, visual-studio-code, gdb, c++17

After debugging this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Checking Debugging Progress!";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a weird message.

`Aborted (core dumped) [1] + Aborted (core dumped)      "/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ua1ohquu.lr2" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-s1zccpii.3ja"`

Interestingly enough that, not always I'm getting this message in the terminal. Is there any specific thing I'm doing wrong that I'm facing this error ? Note that I'm debugging in `Visual Studio Code`, using `Linux` and using the following `.json` file to build the code :

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your code, as shown, is perfect. _"Is there any specific thing I'm doing wrong that I'm facing this error ?"_ - Hard to say, but if all you do is to compile and debug this excellent piece of work, no, you're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo What are the reasons that create this error message while debugging? Maybe I'll be able to stay alert from them from now on.

Comment: I'm trying to understand that myself - but stay on the ball: **You** didn't do anything wrong. The tools you are using are misdiagnosing it (unless I'm totally off).

Comment: The message you are seeing is from the shell, and is telling you that GDB crashed.  To figure out what has actually gone wrong you would likely need to figure out what commands your IDE sent to GDB, and myabe look at the core file that GDB dumped when it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "command" and "args" in the .json file. The command should be "/usr/bin/gdb" and the args should be ["-fdiagnostics-color=always", "-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"]